# Sound not working in Pro Evolution Soccer 2015 and Pro Evolution Soccer 2016

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2015, pro-evolution-soccer-2016

Before I refreshed my PC, Pro Evolution Soccer 2015 and Pro Evolution Soccer 2016 both worked perfectly.

After reinstalling both, the sound stopped working. This is not a problem in any other game.

I tried to update my sound drivers, but they are already up to date.

What can cause this problem, specific to PES 2015 and PES 2016, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `refreshed my pc`?

Comment: Refresh PC is a feature on windows 8.1. when your PC is running slow, you can use it to remove all installed apps, return settings to their defaults without you will not lose your files

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem on Windows 10. It seems PES 2016 (for some strange reason) only supports (the now very old) DirectX 9.0c and not the later versions (i.e. DirectX 10, 11 or 12 which you may already have installed).

Just [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34429) and install DirectX 9.0c from the Microsoft website, and I'm sure everything's going to be fine after that.